# How do you abort from a function using try and catch?

Tags: c++

```
void AddNewPerson(string &firstName, string &lastName, string &id)
{
    try{
        cout <<"Enter first name (a to abort): ";
        cin >> firstName;
        throw firstName;
        cout <<"Enter last name (a to abort): ";
        cin >> lastName;
        throw lastName;
        cout <<"Enter ID Number (a to abort): ";
        cin >> id;
        throw id;
     }
     catch(char x){
     if(x == 'a'){
        //exit here
     }
     }
}
```

I'm trying to exit the function whenever a user wants to abort using the char 'a.' But I'm not sure how to do this using try and catch statements. Any help?

Comment: Exceptions are for exceptional circumstances, not for control flow.

Comment: My professor is requiring that we use try and catch in this circumstance. The requirements for the project say that a user should be able to exit at any step, and we should use try...catch to handle this.

Comment: Shouldn't `catch(char x)` be `catch(int x)`?

Comment: Well, if you always throw after reading the first name, you'll never get the prompt to enter the last name.

Comment: Considering the code is throwing a string, it should be `catch (std::string& x)`.  :P  But that in itself is a bad idea; you should really be throwing and catching a subclass of `std::exception`, unless you have a very good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: I'm guessing you're supposed to exit by throwing an exception if the user enters `a`? In that case, you'd want `if (input == "a") throw something;` after each input. You certainly don't want to throw the inputs themselves.

Comment: Your professor needs smacked for using this as an example to teach try/catch.

Comment: By reading the comments, I feel that this is a misleading use of try and catch since it is a very custom/specific/wierd exercise

Answer (score 2):

What you meant to do was probably something like:

```
cout <<"Enter first name (a to abort): ";
cin >> firstName;
if (firstName == "a") throw firstName;
```

Without the `if` the whole thing doesn't make sense, cause the next lines after `throw` will never be executed.

Answer (score 2):

It might be necessary to show what goes on in a wider context. Suppose you have a loop that calls your function several times:

```
while (true) // endless loop
{
    string firstName, lastName, id;
    AddNewPerson(string &firstName, string &lastName, string &id);
    ...
}
// Do something else
```

You can use exceptions to break the loop:

```
try {
    while (true) // endless loop
    {
        string firstName, lastName, id;
        AddNewPerson(string &firstName, string &lastName, string &id);
        ...
    }
}
catch(EndOfInput x)
{
    // Nothing is actually exceptional here: the user just finished their input
}
// Do something else
```

If you use this construct, change your input function this way:

```
class EndOfInput: public std::exception {};

void AddNewPerson(string &firstName, string &lastName, string &id)
{
    cout <<"Enter first name (a to abort): ";
    cin >> firstName;
    if (firstName == "a")
        throw EndOfInput();
    cout <<"Enter last name (a to abort): ";
    cin >> lastName;
    if (lastName == "a")
        throw EndOfInput();
    cout <<"Enter ID Number (a to abort): ";
    cin >> id;
    if (id == "a")
        throw EndOfInput();
     // No need to catch anything here
 }
```

Note: it's recommended to throw subclasses of `std::exception`, not general classes like `string`, to avoid some sorts of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
void AddNewPerson(string &firstName, string &lastName, string &id)
{
    try{
        cout <<"Enter first name (a to abort): ";
        cin >> firstName;
        if(firstName == "a")
             throw firstName;
        cout <<"Enter last name (a to abort): ";
        cin >> lastName;
        if(lastName== "a")
            throw lastName;
        cout <<"Enter ID Number (a to abort): ";
        cin >> id;
        if(id == "a")
             throw id;

     }
     catch(string x){//catch is for exeptions.
     if(x == "a"){
    //exit here
          return;
 }
 }
}
```

Comment: Supposedly the whole point was to use exceptions.  (Why a professor would pick one of the cases where exceptions *shouldn't* be used, is beside the point.)

Comment: Well I don't know :) , try and catch takes so much memory and in this function are just pointess, I don't know who is the proffesor there.

Comment: That won't compile. `try` must have at least one `catch` handler. Not to mention `std::string` provides `operator==`

Comment: Plus you're throwing an exception of type `std::string` and catching type `char`. What do you think will happen when `throw(id)` is invoked?

Comment: Edited to use throws.

Answer (score 0):

`return` exit a function. I can't see how you'll ever reach the lines beyond the first throw though.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated you should be throwing an instance of `exception` (or a subclass).

```
class abort_exception : public exception{}

//....

void AddNewPerson( string & firstName, string & lastName, string & id )
{

    try
    {
        cout << "Enter first name (a to abort): ";
        cin >> firstName;
        if( firstName == "a" )
            throw abort_exception();
        // ...
    }
    catch( abort_exception& e )
    {
        cerr << "User Aborted.";
    }
}
```

You do not need to `return` from the `catch` block because execution will continue after the block, which does nothing and just returns. You may want to have some return value that lets the caller know if the user aborted or not. In such a case you would have something like:

```
// returns true on success, false on failuer
bool AddNewPerson( string & firstName, string & lastName, string & id )
{
    try
    {
        // ...
    }
    catch( abort_exception& e )
    {
        cerr << "User Aborted.";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `throw` to throw an exception, but if you want to leave the function because of it, you should make sure not to subsequently *catch* it before you actually get out of the function. That's what you're doing in your code, though; you're unconditionally throwing the exception, and then immediately testing what value you threw.

If you're only supposed to exit when the user enters something particular, then make sure you check for that special value *before* you initiate the process of leaving the function. That is, don't throw until *after* you've checked the value:

```
cin >> value;
if (<value-is-special>) {
  throw <something>;
}
```

If you wait until after you catch the exception to check the value, then it's too late. Once you've thrown, you can't go back to where you threw and resume running, in case the user *didn't* enter the special abort indicator.

Your instructor probably intends for you to catch the exception *outside* the function, in the caller. Based on which line of code executes when you're outside the function, you'll know whether you got all the information you requested:

```
try {
  AddNewPerson(...);
  // If you get here, you have all the data about a new person.
} catch (<type>) {
  // If you get here, the user aborted.
}
```

The type of the thing you throw should match the type specified in your `catch` clause. In your code, you're throwing the variable you read your input into. That's fine, but since those variables are strings, the type you catch should be `string` as well. A `catch (char)` clause is legal, but won't catch a thrown `string` because they're not the same types, even though they hold similar kinds of values.

The more typical way to leave a function early is to use `return`, but if your assignment requires you to use exceptions, then so be it.